# Is a Http2 Cross-origin push request possible?

Tags: cross-domain, http2

Say I have a server that serves an HTML file at the url `https://example.com/` and this refers to a css file at the url `https://test.com/mystyles.css`.  Is it possible to push the `mystyles.css` file alongside the html content as part of an HTTP2 connection, so that a browser will use this css content?

I have tried to create such a request using a self-signed certificate on my localhost (and I have pre-created a security exception for both hosts in my browser) by sending the html file when a request arrives at `http://localhost/`, and pushing the css with a differing hostname/port in the `:authority` or `Host` header. However, on a full-page refresh, the CSS file is fetched in a separate request from the server, rather than using the pushed css file.

See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/benwhite-deltas/f667d8db5a1ad837eabe) for a file that I have been using to test this. If I visit `http://localhost:8080/` then the text is red, but if I visit `http://test:8080/` it is green, implying that the pushed content is used if the origin is the same.

Is there a combination of headers that needs to be used for this to work? Possibly invoking CORS?

Comment: According to the spec, if you get it right with the certificates it won't be illegal. However, I don't think that browsers accept it for now.

Comment: Do the specs say this explicitly? Can you provide a link?

Comment: Second before last paragraph of [section  8.2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7540#section-8.2), then section 10.1. And then to another RFC, this one for when a server is authoritative under TLS, here: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2818#section-3 .

Comment: Consider to add `;crossorigin` attribute at the end of `Link:` header. See examples from [here](https://w3c.github.io/preload/#developer-server-and-proxy-initiated-fetching) (or [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/preload/#h-early-fetch-of-critical-resources))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is theoretically possible according to this [blog post from a Chrome developer advocate](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/h2-push-tougher-than-i-thought/#you-can-push-items-for-other-origins) from 2017.

> As the owners of developers.google.com/web, we could get our server to
>   push a response containing whatever we wanted for android.com, and set
>   it to cache for a year.
>
> ...
>
> You can't push assets for
>   any origin, but you can push assets for origins which your connection
>   is "authoritative" for.
>
> If you look at the certificate for developers.google.com, you can see
>   it's authoritative for all sorts of Google origins, including
>   android.com.
>
> Viewing certificate information in Chrome Now, I lied a little,
>   because when we fetch android.com it'll perform a DNS lookup and see
>   that it terminates at a different IP to developers.google.com, so
>   it'll set up a new connection and miss our item in the push cache.
>
> We could work around this using an ORIGIN frame. This lets the
>   connection say "Hey, if you need anything from android.com, just ask
>   me. No need to do any of that DNS stuff", as long as it's
>   authoritative. This is useful for general connection coalescing, but
>   it's pretty new and only supported in Firefox Nightly.
>
> If you're using a CDN or some kind of shared host, take a look at the
>   certificate, see which origins could start pushing content for your
>   site. It's kinda terrifying. Thankfully, no host (that I'm aware of) offers full control over HTTP/2 push, and is unlikely to thanks to this little note in the spec: ...

In practice, it sounds like it's possible if your certificate has authority over the other domains and they're hosted at the same IP address, but it also depends on browser support. I was personally trying to do this with Cloudflare and found that they don't support cross-origin push (similar to the blog post author's observations about CDNs in 2017).